# Simplest way to negate $all in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am running the following query on `mongoDB 3.4` using through my application. Basically, I want to find the documents, which the attributes array has elements which match with the specified criteria using **$elemMatch**

```
db.collectionName.find({
    attributes: {
        $all: [{
            $elemMatch: {
                "name": "manufacturer",
                "value": "val1",
                "status": 1
            }
        }, {
            $elemMatch: {
                "name": "model",
                "value": "val2",
                "status": 1
            }
        }]
    }
})
```

But, concurrent to this, I want to run another find query to find the records for which the above find conditions fail, that is even **one** `$elemMatch` fails

How can I acheive this?

**If possible, I'd rather not change the array I'm passing to $all**

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/ and the de-morgan theorem if required in your case.

Comment: De-Morgan would require me to edit the elements of the array so I was trying to avoid it. `$not` worked though, so if you post an answer I'll accept it now.

Comment: Not really clear on what case you are trying to present, but `$not` in the context "I think" you mean does not require any changes to the array arguments. It's simply a "negation" which would be applied before `$all` in the query expression. Unless you mean something else. Could do with a data sample and the expected results.

Comment: `**$not**` would not. `**De-Morgans**` would.

Comment: Show a sample. If you think `$ne` is required on every element, then you're likely mistaken. That's why I think you really need to post some sample data and the expected result. I see a clear case for `$not` in what I "think" you actually mean. But my expect results may be different from what you expect. So alleviate the confusion, show us something that we can reproduce from. It will help you get a correct answer if you do.

Comment: @NeilLunn check the second part of the answer I just posted. That alternative wouldve required a `$ne`

Comment: Dude. Really simple concept here. You actually do not demonstrate any data in the question or the expected result. Therefore, anyone viewing this simply sees "a query with no context whatsoever". So does your answer work for you? Possibly does. But it's just plain not useful for anyone unless they can clearly see what was supposed to happen and why the expression works or does not. "Context is **everything**" and without it the question and answer are simply not useful at all. That's why my advice was to "give some context". Besides, you probably actually mean `$nor`, yet still don't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **$not** operator as suggessted by @nullpointer in the comments, I was able to do it this way:

```
db.collectionName.find({
    attributes: {
        $not: {
            $all: [{
                $elemMatch: {
                    "name": "manufacturer",
                    "value": "val1",
                    "status": 1
                }
            }, {
                $elemMatch: {
                    "name": "model",
                    "value": "val2",
                    "status": 1
                }
            }]
        }
    }
})
```

Another alternative I was trying to avoid but can be used is the **De-Morgan's theorems**, accoring to which:

**NOT (A AND B AND C)** = **NOT A OR NOT B OR NOT C**, which would make the query

```
db.collectionName.find({
    attributes: {
        $or: [{
            $elemMatch: {
                "name": "manufacturer",
                "value": {"$ne": "val1"},
                "status": 1
            }
        }, {
            $elemMatch: {
                "name": "model",
                "value": {"$ne": "val2"},
                "status": 1
            }
        }]
    }

})
```